# Google Cloud Messages как получить ответ от сервера

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-messages

Использую эту [библиотеку](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-gcm-service) в описании сказано что  могу получить следующие  ответы от сервера.

**GCM response**

```
{
    "multicast_id": 216,
    "success": 3,
    "failure": 3,
    "canonical_ids": 1,
    "results": [
        { "message_id": "1:0408" },
        { "error": "Unavailable" },
        { "error": "InvalidRegistration" },
        { "message_id": "1:1516" },
        { "message_id": "1:2342", "registration_id": "32" },
        { "error": "NotRegistered"}
    ]
}
```

**module response**

```
{
    "multicast_id": 216,
    "success_length": 3,
    "failures_length": 3,
    "failures": {
        "NotRegistered": ["42"],
        "Unavailable": ["8"],
        "InvalidRegistration": ["15"]
    },
    "canonical_ids_length": 1,
    "canonical_ids": [
        {
            "message_id": "1:2342",
            "registration_id": "23",
            "new_registration_id": "32"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Simple (plain-text response)
GCM response**

```
id=1:2342
registration_id=32
```

**module response**

```
{
    "id": "1:2342",
    "registration_id": "32"
    "old_registration_id": "14"
}
```

**Вопрос:** как мне извлечь ответ если запрос я посылаю  таким образом

```
    sender.sendMessage(message.toString(), token, false, function(err, data) {
        if (!err) {
            console.log(data)
        } else {
            console.log(err)
        }
    });
```

а в `data` мне возвращается либо строка `{ id: '0:1462523393672289]ee2b8a002eefaa' }` если token пользователя действительный  либо `{ NotRegistered }` если token пользователя недействительный

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделал запрос таким образом:

```
var request = require('request');

var reg_id = 'MyRegistration_id';


var messageBody =
{ "collapse_key": "data",
    "time_to_live": 1000,
    "delay_while_idle": false,
    "data": {
        "message": "Http request test message",
    },
    "to" : reg_id
};


var options = {
    url: 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send',
    json: true,
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'key=MyCustomApiKey',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        // use for plain/text data
        // 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8'
    },
    body: messageBody
};

function callback(error, response, body) {
    console.log('Response code : ' + response.statusCode)
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        console.log("Response body: " + JSON.stringify(body))
    }
    if (error != null){
        console.log(error)
    }
}

request(options, callback);
```